# Can't open link with dynamic content on Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the HTML below on my Ionic app:

```
<a ng-href="#/app/perfil/{{ notification.Notification.model_id }}">
    <img ng-src="{{ notification.Notification.photo }}" class="profile-pic">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="notification.Notification.name">{{ notification.Notification.name }}</h2>
    <p ng-bind-html="notification.Notification.title">{{ notification.Notification.title }}</p>
</a>
```

As you can see, it set the user ID after loading a JSON file. This link works fine on a browser, but for some reason when I try on a real device, my xcode returns an error:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown
```

All my data is being served on a HTTPs URL.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I've changed my `ng-href` to `ui-sref` and it worked - actually, `ui-sref` makes much more sense in this case.

If any one is having the same issue, please read more details here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

My code:

```
<a ui-sref="appPerfil.perfil-amigo({ user_id: notification.Notification.model_id })">
    <img ng-src="{{ notification.Notification.photo }}" class="profile-pic">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="notification.Notification.name">{{ notification.Notification.name }}</h2>
    <p ng-bind-html="notification.Notification.title">{{ notification.Notification.title }}</p>
</a>
```